# React Native Error: Couldn't read row 0 col 0 from CursorWindow

Tags: react-native, row, warnings, col

I've searched for this error here and was unable to find solution for my problem.

My app worked fine until one day this error came onto emulator, I can not determine what caused it, all the issues relevant to this error are suggesting some errors with sql, sqllite and etc. but I don't use any of these in my app. Any help would be appreciated. This is the screenshot of a warning I get when I start my RN app.

[image: React Native App Warning I get]

Comment: Can you add your code and the library that you have used?

Comment: That's the problem. I am not sure what caused this, because I am not connecting to any sql or sqllite base or anything that the simmilar posts are pointing to. This happens when my app starts, and when it needs to download some data in order to show it (some pictures, videos, pdf files and so on). I hope that someone who experienced this or smth simmilar knows what could possibly cause this warning to show.

And the other strange thing is that this only pop ups on android version. IOS version works fine